# javascript reload html page only when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to reload my page every x seconds if a checkbox is checked.
I found a code snipped for the reload and added an if statement.
But it doesn't work. The script only works without the if statemant.
What do I miss?

```
<!-- Reload page-->
setTimeout(function()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('CheckBoxReloadPage').checked)
            {
                location.reload(true);
                document.getElementById("CheckBoxReloadPage").checked = true;
            }
        },
        5000);
```

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: when u reload the page se to it that checkbox remains checked.

Comment: thanks, i edited the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page is correctly reloaded after 5 seconds, but **only** if you checked the checkbox in the first 5 seconds after your page has loaded.

If you want the check to occur *every 5 seconds* instead of *5 seconds from now*, change `setTimeout` to `setInterval`.

Then, as you may imagine, when your page reloads, everything will be back to the way it was - including the checkbox. You will have to store the state of your checkbox in, say, the session storage and set it to your checkbox upon loading:

```
// Gets the reference of the checkbox once and for all
var myCheckbox = document.getElementById('CheckBoxReloadPage');

// Sets the initial value of the checkbox to the stored state
myCheckbox.checked = sessionStorage.getItem('checkbox-state');

// Listen to every change on the checkbox
myCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    // Store the state of the checkbox to the session storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('checkbox-state', event.target.checked);
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (myCheckbox.checked) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you, thats the point. Now the refresh works if the checkbox is checked. But the recheck doesn't work.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I haven't understood this point. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems that the 'myCheckbox.addEventListener' doesn't work. If I put "alert('Test')" inside and check the box, nothing happens.

Comment: Here, take a look at this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8oulQbY9GLuJmVyLSHau?p=preview). I think that your problem is the order of execution of your JavaScript code: if the code is written **before** the checkbox, the `document.getElementById` function will not find any element - since it is not in the DOM yet. You could just wrap all your snippet in the [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).